# How to access a property of the component that the Sender parameter is referencing (the component that fired the event)

Tags: delphi, pascal

I am new to delphi and pascal and was wondering if there was a way to get/access a property of the component that the Sender is referencing within the procedure.

More specifically I would like to make a procedure that changes the caption property of a label, that label being the component that **Sender** is referencing.
I imagine that procedure looking something like:

```
procedure TForm1.LabelEdit(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Sender.caption := 'Sample Text';
end;
```

Naturally this wouldn't work but can something like or something similar to this be done?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. It suggests that a `TLabel` has an `OnEdit` event, but it hasn't. (And `TLabel` controls cannot even be edited at runtime out of the box.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although the example in your question doesn't really make sense (it incorrectly suggests that a `TLabel` has an `OnEdit` event), it is very much possible to use the `Sender` parameter to obtain information about the sender object.

Create a new VCL application and drop a number of `TLabel` controls on the form. Give them different captions (like `Dog`, `Cat`, `Rabbit`, `Horse` etc.).

Now select them all in the form designer and then use the **Object Inspector** to create a common `OnClick` handler for them. You can name it `LabelClick` (write `LabelClick` in the edit field next to `OnClick` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

This will create the following empty method:

```
procedure TForm1.LabelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;
```

It has a `Sender` parameter of type `TObject`. Now, depending on how this method is called, `Sender` can be any `TObject` (a button, a form, a bitmap, ...), or `nil` (no object at all).

But in our case, we expect this method mainly to be called in response to the labels being clicked on, and in these cases, the `Sender` will be the corresponding `TLabel` object.

Let's try to display the caption of the clicked label in a message box!

We try

```
procedure TForm1.LabelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(Sender.Caption); // won't compile!
end;
```

But this doesn't even compile! The problem is that `TObject` has no public `Caption` member. But `TLabel` does, so we can write

```
procedure TForm1.LabelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(TLabel(Sender).Caption);
end;
```

Here we are telling the compiler that we *know* `Sender` will always be a `TLabel`, and we ask it to assume that it is.

But this will crash or do other bad things if somehow this method is called with a non-`TLabel` `Sender`. So it is safer to do

```
procedure TForm1.LabelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage((Sender as TLabel).Caption);
end;
```

This does the same, except that the compiler will now create code that checks at runtime that `Sender` really is a `TLabel` object. If not, the code will raise an exception. That's much better than the kind of memory corruption/AV issues you may get with the unsafe cast above.

Arguably even better is

```
procedure TForm1.LabelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TLabel then
    ShowMessage(TLabel(Sender).Caption);
end;
```

This will also test the type of `Sender` at runtime. If it is a label, we display its caption. Otherwise, we choose to do nothing. Notice that there is no point in using a safe (and slightly, slightly, slower) `as` cast here.

Comment: TObject is the common basis of all objects. You can therefore assign any object to a variable of the type TObject. TObject does not implement either the 'Caption' or 'Text' property. Therefore, you need to place the required object template over the object.
Ways are:
TMyObject (Sender) .abc   or
(Sender as TMyObject).abc
The prerequisite is that the variable Sender is assigned and the sender corresponds to the assigned template.

Answer (score 1):

You cast `Sender` to the type that the event connects.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(Sender) then
    (Sender as TButton).Caption := 'Clicked';
end;
```

If you're sharing the event among different types of controls, you can test first to see what type it is:

```
procedure TForm1.ControlClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Sender is TEdit) then
    TEdit(Sender).Text := 'Clicked'
  else if (Sender is TButton) then
    TButton(Sender).Caption := 'Clicked';
end;
  
end;
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the procedure is not called with `nil`, so `(Sender as TButton).Caption` would then lead to an access violation.

Comment: @AmigoJack: If it's a ButtonClick event, it's usually pretty safe to assume that Sender is the control that was clicked. But for people who want to be absolutely sure, I've edited the code in the first code block.

Comment: ...or using the `is` operator right away to ensure it really is a `TButton` like you treat it afterwards. Or like your second example does.

Comment: @AmigoJack: Strange you didn't leave the same comment on Andreus' answer, as there's no test for Sender being nil in any of the examples there either. Is there a reason you singled me out?

Comment: Because he explained it beforehand, then shows imperfect examples with additional explanations (AV may arise), then concludes with one full correct example. Did you read it as one whole answer, or did you just look at the code boxes? It's nothing personal - it's about precision. If you have other answers that are too imprecise I'll comment on those, too.

Comment: Note that `Sender is TEdit` will be false if Sender is nil

Comment: @AmigoJack: `Assigned(Sender)` prevents an AV with a `nil` value, and `Sender as TButton` will raise an exception if Sender is not the proper class. It won't raise an AV. Also, I did in fact show proper code, as it works just fine. If you don't expect Sender to be a TButton, then use my second example. My example is precise and clear in both cases.