# How to refer to the current object in Delphi?

Tags: windows, user-interface, delphi, vcl, rad-studio

I give long names to objects (buttons, panels etc.) in Delphi in order to keep my project tidy.

For example, a button's name can be "A_Button_That_Saves_Settings_To_Regedit".

In that case, coding with a long name is annoying.

"Self" keyword refers to Form.

Is there any keyword in Delphi which refers to the current object?

For example:

```
procedure TForm1.Image1OnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  [keyword that refers to "Image1"].Picture.Graphic := [Something];
end;
```

or

```
procedure TForm1.Label1OnMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  [keyword that refers to "Label1"].Font.Color := RGB(255,255,255);
end;
```

Comment: See [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209155/how-to-access-a-property-of-the-component-that-the-sender-parameter-is-referenci)

Comment: There is none since the `Sender` parameter could also be `nil` and the procedure's name can be anything - it is neither bound to the `Label1` or `Image1` part, nor to the `OnMouseEnter` or `OnClick` part.

Comment: @AmigoJack I think "Sender as..." keyword works like a charm.

Comment: That's no keyword, but instead a variable and an operator. Should `Sender` have a value of `nil` then `(Sender as TLabel).Font` will crash, since `.Font` is inaccessible for `nil`.

Comment: @AmigoJack "Sender as" works for me due to I always use "Sender" like this: "Sender: TObject". Anyway, your argument is true ofcourse.

Comment: Sender can not be trusted, it could be something complete different

Comment: it is easy possible that a complete different object uses this very same method for its OnClick. In that case the Sender can be any of those 2 (or even more objects). For this to work you need to test `Sender` for all possible types and write different code for each. That makes things a lot more difficult to read than just use its name. What is the problem with using the long name ? I do this too, you don't have to type them the editor will help you with that

Comment: Invoke code completition with ``Ctrl + Space``